# Using the Map Method to Call a Class Method

Tags: swift

I am learning about the map method in Swift.  The standard definition is

> The map method takes a function (transform), and returns an array containing the results of calling transform on each element in the array.

This makes sense.  If I wanted to add a text string to each string element in an array I could do the following.

```
var stringArray = ["Blue", "Green", "Brown", "White"]
var newStringArray = stringArray.map({"\($0)Color"})
```

This adds "Color" to each element.

My question has to do with the proper use of the map function.  If I were to use it to create a number of objects  with class methods would that be acceptable use.  For example if I have an array with a number of objects that are used to create new objects, is calling a class function with the map method ok?  It works I just want to make sure it's not bad practice.

```
XMLParsedDataArray!.map({Article.createFLOArticleWithStructure($0, inManagedObjectContext: self.articleContext)})
```

Each element in XMLParsedDataArray is a structure as defined below.

```
struct DateTitleLink
{
    var date : NSDate?
    var title : String?
    var link : String?
}
```

The createFLOArticleWithStructure method create an Article object and store it in Core Data.

Technically I am not transforming each element of the array, I am just using the map method to call the class function.

Comment: I think that if you don't use the results of Map() later using For-In loop is more explicit and appropriate.  And it doesn't matter if you use class method or any other.

Comment: I do not think it's a bad practice.  It's actually a good practice.  By using map() you indicate to the compiler your intention more clearly than with a for-loop.  On top of that, using map() is a step towards using lazy sequence, which is something that you could consider.  There is a brilliant set of articles by Airspeed Velocity to check out more on the subject: http://airspeedvelocity.net/2014/07/26/lazy-by-name-lazy-by-nature/